# Why Rails applications run Garbage Collector at all?

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, rack, application-server, preemption

I was pretty sure, that all [Rack](http://rack.github.com/) application servers (I had some experience with [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) and [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/)) were creating single process for every worker when they were created, and its state was "frozen".

Whenever app server receives request to handle, it forks from the master process and all further changes to forked process are separated from the original process. They benefit from copy-on-write optimizations and are safe to be "damaged" by processing request. All changes to the environment affect only single process that will be preempted anyway.

If my vision of RoR application stack was true, there should be almost no need of garbage collection, unless serving single request would take a lot of time and memory (which usually is not the case).

On the other hand, [question about GC measurements done with NewRelic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387664/ruby-gc-execution-exceeding-250-320ms-per-request) and it's answers led me to conclusion that I must be completely wrong.

Can someone clarify this process?

Comment: are you sure Rails has a GarbageCollector...? Unicorn/Passenger does not create a separated process for each request. They forks multiple workers that serve requests.

Comment: @slivu: 1. Well, Ruby has a GC. Rails is written in Ruby, and application servers spawn Ruby processes. 2. `fork()`ing multiple workers means creating child processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rack applications servers are **not** forking at each request, only during initialization:

1. First, the environment is loaded in one process
2. Then, the server fork several workers
3. Then all requests are distributed among these processes

That's why the Garbage collector is used to keep each process memory clean & stable.

Comment: If you were right, how come that applying monkeypatch or changing global variable is not persistent between requests?

Comment: It depends, where is your monkey path ? in which environment ? how do you changed that global variable ?

Comment: I made some tests to check this, and it seems that I stranded into wrong conclusions because changes made to environment are not shared between workers.

Comment: If you changed some global variable AFTER the workers have forked, you change won't propagate for sure, it's different processes. But this is not something people do, if you need to change your environment, just restart your server ;)